# How do I find my missing songs from last.fm?

Tags: music, last.fm

My disk failed with all my music with it, lots of them. But luckily, I scrobbled every song to last.fm.

I am looking for a way to scan my disk for my songs and check last.fm and tell me which songs are missing from my disk that are present on last.fm.

So to recap: I would need to log into my last.fm account and compile a list of all the songs I have scrobbled and then scan my computer for missing songs.

Is there a program or script that does this? I don't mind it being a shell script even.

Edit: I know this is possible because I came close to this a little time ago. I created a PHP script (web page) that got all my songs through Last.fm API and then went through my files on disk and read their id3 tag. I got very close: the program showed missing songs, but there were many small issues (id3 reading was buggy, tags had different data, etc.) that required more programming time that I didn't have.

Comment: MIght be near impossible. You could check the [last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api) if there's even a way to find out *all* your listened tracks.

Comment: Check my Edit paragraph where I've now answered your comment.

Comment: Ah, neat. Maybe you can share this script so people have something to work on?